# Do we need to have same LinkedServices on All ADF Environments

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to implement CI/CD for ADF instance using arm_templates(Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements)
Would like to understand the following:

1. Do we need to have same Linked services on all environments (DEV,SIT,UAT,PROD)?
2. If i don't have the Linked services in SIT environment to the ones that i have in Dev environment my pipeline is failing with `"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters xxxxx' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time.`
3. In Case we have 2 Teams working on Same ADF, adding Team 1 and Team 2, If the Team 1 want to deploy to SIT/UAT which only have Team 1 Linked Services Can they do it? Will the arm_template_parameter.json file wont cause any error?

Kindly let me know

Thanks

We are facing the error in #2

Answer (score 0):

> You need to consider using parameters in the linked services. And all
> these parameters will appear to you as part of CI/CD release process
> and you can pass the values to the parameters according to the
> environment in which you are deploying resources.